# Как добавить кастомный div для каждого отзыва в плагине отзывов?

Tags: php, wordpress

Я использую этот плагин для отображения отзывов  [testimonials](https://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonials-widget/) и я хочу добавить кастомный div для каждого отзыва.Я нашел этот  [пример](https://nodedesk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202244572-How-do-I-customize-my-testimonial-list-and-widget-output-) для изменения вывода ,но я все еще не понимаю как это работает.Как все таки добавить блок?

Comment: Изменил.Ошибся.